# How to get GA4 Account and Property details?

Tags: r, google-analytics-4

How to get GA4 Account and Property details using R? I am able to get only Universal analytics details using

```
accounts <- google_analytics_accounts()
properties <- google_analytics_properties(accounts)
```

Tried using

```
ga4_properties <- google_analytics_4_properties()
```

But it throws up errors

Comment: Where do these functions come from?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.